# Assign new DataFrame column base on list condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to assign the new column to my DataFrame base on condition - if row.id is one of the bad_cat value.

```
bad_cat = [71,84]
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'id' : [1,2,71,5,84]})
df['type'] = df[df.id in bad_cat]

Output:
name   id  type
a      1   False
b      2   False
c      71  True
d      5   False
e      84  True
```

It seems my code doesn't work - could you explain how to do it.

Comment: `df['type'] = df['id'].isin(bad_cat)`

Answer (score 0):

The most intuitive answer would be one provided by Quang Hoang using `.isin` method. This will create a mask resulting in a series of bool statements:

```py
df['type'] = df['id'].isin(bad_cat)
```

The other approach could be to use index - this can be faster solution under some circumstances. After setting index to column that will be assessed against values provided in the list, you can use `.loc` for slicing and setting `type` to `True` for vlaues that match those on the list.

```py
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df['type'] = False
df['type'].loc[bad_cat] = True
```

for both solutions output will be:

```
   name   type
id            
1     a  False
2     b  False
71    c   True
5     d  False
84    e   True
```

> **Note**: that values in the column that serves as an index does not have to be unique.